# calculating ordered and unordered permutation - C

Tags: c, recursion, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

Trying to calculate the ordered permutations and unordered permutations of a number and selection in C.
The recursive factorial function is working, the permutation results are giving random memory locations

./permutation
 
Enter number of items: 5
Enter number to select: 2

There are 1.#INF00 ordered permutations
There are 1.#INF00 unordered permutations

```
#include <stdio.h>

double ordered_permutation(double total_items, double selection);
double unordered_permutation(double total_items, double selection);
double factorial( double number);

int main() {

    double items;
    double selection;
    printf("Enter number of items: ");
    scanf("%f", &items);
    printf("Enter number to select: ");
    scanf("%f", &selection);

    double ordered_perm;
    double unordered_perm;
    ordered_perm = ordered_permutation( items, selection );
    unordered_perm = unordered_permutation( items , selection );

    printf("There are %f ordered permutations\nThere are %f unordered permutations\n", ordered_perm, unordered_perm);

    return 0;
}

/*    total_items!/ ( total_items! - selection! )    */
double ordered_permutation(double total_items, double selection){
    double permutations;

    permutations = factorial(total_items)/ ( factorial(total_items) - factorial(selection) );

    return permutations;
}

/*    total_items!/ ( ( total_items! - selection! ) selection! )    */
double unordered_permutation(double total_items, double selection){
    double permutations;

    permutations = factorial(total_items)/ ( ( factorial(total_items) - factorial(selection) ) * factorial(selection));

    return permutations;
}

double factorial( double number){
    if( number <= 1 )
        return 1;
    else 
        return  number * factorial((number-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the denominator calls to:

```
    factorial(total_items - selection)
```

and

```
    (factorial(total_items- selection) * factorial(selection))
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite the answer to your question, but using recursion to calculate *large* factorials can cause stack overflows [and is relatively] slow.

Also, you're using `double` for things that are counts and indexes.  And factorials are based upon multiplying whole integers and the results can only be an integer.

Here's a non-recursive factorial function:

```
#if 1
typedef int value_t;
#else
typedef long long value_t;
#endif

value_t
factorial(value_t n)
{
    value_t i;
    value_t f;

    f = 1;

    for (i = 1;  i <= n;  ++i)
        f *= i;

    return f;
}
```